# NHibernate: exclusive locking

Tags: nhibernate, locking

In NHibernate, I want to retrieve an instance, and put an exclusive lock on the record that represents the retrieved entity on the database.

Right now, I have this code:

```
With.Transaction (session, IsolationLevel.Serializable, delegate
{
    ICriteria crit = session.CreateCriteria (typeof (TarificationProfile));

    crit.SetLockMode (LockMode.Upgrade);

    crit.Add (Expression.Eq ("Id", tarificationProfileId));

    TarificationProfile profile = crit.UniqueResult<TarificationProfile> ();

    nextNumber = profile.AttestCounter;

    profile.AttestCounter++;

    session.SaveOrUpdate (profile);
});
```

As you can see, I set the LockMode for this Criteria to 'Upgrade'.
This issues an SQL statement for SQL Server which uses the `updlock` and `rowlock` locking hints:

```
SELECT ... FROM MyTable with (updlock, rowlock)
```

However, I want to be able to use a real exclusive lock.  That is, prevent that others can read this very same record, until I have released the lock.
In other words, I want to be able to use an `xlock` locking hint, instead of an `updlock`.

I don't know how (or even if) I can achieve that ....  Maybe somebody can give me some hints about this :)

If it is really necessary, I can use the SQLQuery functionality of NHibernate, and write my own SQL Query, but, I'd like to avoid that as much as possible.

Comment: Why do you want to achieve a exclusive lock? There are probably other solutions.

Comment: Why ? Because it is necessary ... My entity contains a counter that should be used, and I must absolutely be sure that this counter is used correctly...

Comment: Shouldn't you lock when reading?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to lock when reading, but this is what i can't do, or at least, NHibernate can't do it.
I want NHibernate to issue a select .. FROM table with (xlock) statement, but it doesn't do that.

Comment: Does all the reading code use a IsolationLevel of Serializable?  Witch RDBMS and verison are you using?

Comment: Yes it does.
The RDMBS is SQL Server2005 sp3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A HQL DML query will accomplish your update without needing a lock.

This is available in NHibernate 2.1, but is not yet in the reference documentation. The Java [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct) is very close to the NHibernate implementation.

Assuming you are using ReadCommitted Isolation, you can then safely read your value back inside the transaction.

```
With.Transaction (session, IsolationLevel.Serializable, delegate
{
    session.CreateQuery( "update TarificationProfile t set t.AttestCounter = 1 + t.AttestCounter where t.id=:id" )
        .SetInt32("id", tarificationProfileId)
        .ExecuteUpdate();

    nextNumber = session.CreateQuery( "select AttestCounter from TarificationProfile where Id=:id" )
        .SetInt32("id", id )
        .UniqueResult<int>();
}
```

Depending on your table and column names, the generated SQL will be:

```
update TarificationProfile
set    AttestCounter = 1 + AttestCounter
where  Id = 1 /* @p0 */

select tarificati0_.AttestCounter as col_0_0_
from   TarificationProfile tarificati0_
where  tarificati0_.Id = 1 /* @p0 */
```

Comment: Nice, but I need to know the next AttestCounter as well.  So, I need to retrieve the new value ...

Comment: @Frederik Updated the example to fetch the new value

Comment: Are you sure that you'll get the correct AttestCounter ?
I mean, are there no racing conditions waiting to happen here, or is it solved by the Serializable isolation level ?

Comment: Any conclusion on this topic? I would love to know if this approach works or not. (if it did work, you should accept the answer)

Comment: Frederik: you don't even need serializable - readcommitted is fine - because you write before you read inside the tx.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt it can be done from NHibernate. Personally, I would use a stored procedure to do what you're trying to accomplish.

**Update:** Given the continued downvotes I'll expand on this. Frederick is asking how to use locking hints, which are syntax- and implementation-specific details of his underlying database engine, from his ORM layer. This is the wrong level to attempt to perform such an operation - even if it was possible (it isn't), the likelihood it would ever work consistently across all NHibernate-supported databases is vanishingly low.

It's great Frederick's eventual solution didn't require pre-emptive exclusive locks (which kill performance and are generally a bad idea unless you know what you're doing), but my answer is valid. Anyone who stumbles across this question and wants to do exclusive-lock-on-read from NHibernate - firstly: don't, secondly: if you have to, use a stored procedure or a SQLQuery.

Answer (score 1):

If all you read are done with a IsolationLevel of Serializable and all the write are also done with a IsolationLevel of Serializable I don't see why you need to do any locking of database rows your self.

So the serialize keeps the data safe, now we still have the problem of possible dead locks....

If the deadlocks are not common, just putting the [start transaction, read, update, save] in a retry loop when you get a deadlock may be good enough.

Otherwise a simple “select for update” statement generated directly (e.g. not with nhibernate) could be used to stop another transaction reading the row before it is changed.

However I keep thinking, that if the update rate is fast enough to get lots of deadlocks a ORM may not be the correct tool for the update, or the database schema may need redesigning to avoid the value that has to be read/written (e.g calculation it when reading the data)

Comment: Even with Serializable, a read will only take out a shared lock. If there a multiple similar transactions accessing this table (let's say the same piece of code concurrently running on separate threads), this will result in a deadlock as neither thread can upgrade to an exclusive lock to perform the write.

Answer (score 0):

You could use isolation level "repeatable read" if you want to make sure that values you read from the database don't change during the transaction. But you have to do this in all critical transactions. Or you lock it in the critical reading transaction with an upgrade lock.

Comment: thx for your response, can you elaborate a bit more on that ?
I use one transaction, in where i read the entity (right now with an updlock), and I save the updated entity in the same transaction.

Comment: So the entity can't change during this transaction. Other transactions can read the value, and they can see your changes during their transaction. If they don't like this, they have to make their own lock. Or use "repeatable read".